# Strange issue with mouse

Tags: mouse, mouse-click

Hardware in question:
Mouse: Skiller Sharkoon SGM3 (usable wireless or with cable)
Laptop: Lenovo Legion Y740-15

When I turn on my mouse or plug it in via cable I can't do a left click anywhere. That also goes for the left touchpad button. The situation is the same when I use the mouse via cable. When I turn off the mouse, the left touchpad button works again. However, when I pull out the dongle (or the cable if I use the mouse via cable) the left touchpad button remains unuseable. The only way to resolve the problem then is pressing CTRL-ALT-DEL and then to chose "Abort".

Sometimes when a windows is open when I turn on the mouse, I can use left click within this window. But if I close it / minimize it and go back to the desktop the left click stops working again. However, I can open a context menu with right click and the left click will work inside the menu.

Anyone have an idea what's going on here?

Comment: Have you tried another mouse?

Comment: I only have this one

Comment: Update the UNAV mouse software for your system from the Lenovo support site

Comment: It already is up to date.

Comment: The mouse does not appear to be compliant with the computer. As you note, unplug the mouse and restart the computer allows the touchpad to work. You need a new mouse. Note: I have (and always have had) Lenovo/ IBM ThinkPads

Comment: @John _"The mouse does not appear to be compliant with the computer"_ is an unhelpful non-answer. OP has already realized that the mouse is causing some problems. Their goal is to get it working. Considering that all mice are just USB HID devices nowadays and should work everywhere, it's not an unreasonable expectation.

Comment: I noted that removing the mouse and restarting makes the laptop work properly. My own mice work fine with my thinkpads. So there is something wrong with the mouse. That is my thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Same case was being happened with me. I have Dell wireless mouse and working on windows 7. I was scared of this behavior that when I left click on mouse on any browser, file explorer or Filzilla then it was  getting backward randomly.
I have recalled what are the changes I have done recently so I have have **switched off experimental features of Chrome** and this issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with USB hub rather than the mouse. This happened on my old lenevo laptop while the same mouse worked perfectly on the new one. Here's what you need to do to fix. Open Device Manager and see if any of the USB ports is showing a Warning icon on it. If yes, just reinstall the device driver and it should work. One done, open your browser and perform a [click test](https://www.clickspeedtester.com/), it will tell if the mouse event is detected properly. In my case, this fixed the issue!